# Why can enum values have large (>int) values?

Tags: c, enums

After I have defined an enum like this:

```
typedef enum { x = 1ULL<<40 } e;
```

it seems that the expression 'x' evaluates to 1UL<<40.

However, C11 6.4.4.3 says "An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type int."

Incidentally this saves my day, since I want enum values > 1<<32. However, I need to know *how* this can be; I'm a bit nervous to write code that isn't standards compliant.

I tried this code:

```
int main() {
        printf("%zu %zu %lx\n", sizeof(e), sizeof(x), x);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall` (gcc 8.3.1, linux x86_64), it outputs: `8 8 10000000000`.

If I change %lx to %llx, I get a compile warning and the same output, which indicates x is long-sized.

Based on my reading of the spec, I would expect compile warnings and output `4 4 0`.

Comment: There is also "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer
type. The choice of type is implementation-defined" c17dr § 6.7.2.2 4  AFAIK, the type being wide is OK, but not the `1ULL<<40`. Hmmmm

Comment: Note that I'm violating §6.7.2.2 2, which says the enumeration constant *shall* have a value representable as an `int`. So my code is invalid C according to the spec. Maybe this allows them to extend the language without contradicting the spec?

Comment: I would not rely on this code to work and would find another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler extensions. For example, with clang:

```
$ CFLAGS=-Weverything make example && ./example
cc -Weverything    example.c   -o example
example.c:3:16: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int'
      (1099511627776 is too large) [-Wpedantic]
typedef enum { x = 1ULL<<40 } e;
               ^   ~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
8 8 10000000000
```

And with gcc:

```
$ CFLAGS='-Wall -pedantic' make example && ./example
cc -Wall -pedantic    example.c   -o example
example.c:3:20: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’ [-Wpedantic]
 typedef enum { x = 1ULL<<40 } e;
                    ^~~~
8 8 10000000000
```

Comment: These warnings are nice, but to me it seems that both clang and gcc produce incorrect behavour; the spec does say sizeof(x) should equal 4, not 8. How do they get away with this? Is there some gcc flag I'm missing that will give me output `4 4 0`? Or can they claim that sizeof may be 8 because there is somehow undefined behavour somewhere?

Comment: @ErikCarstensen the spec doesn't say that the size of any type should equal 4.  Also, the spec says that if the program has a constraint violation then the compiler should issue a diagnostic, which it did. (And consequently, the spec doesn't define the behaviour of such a program).  You can prevent generation of an executable by using compiler flags such as `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror`

Comment: Technically, I think this would be a variant (it is not standard C), not an extension. If the standard says the type is `int`, and the type in the implementation is not `int`, the implementation does not conform to the C standard. (We could write a strictly conforming program that could detect the difference.)

Comment: 6.7.2.2 describes other possible types, so who knows.

Comment: @M.M answers my question. @EricPostpischil, I don't understand how one could write a conforming program that detects the difference, because §6.7.2.2 2 says the enumeration constant shall have a value representable as an `int`.